# How to know when Firebase has finished downloading all the nodes in a snapshot using Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function which fetches `messages` from `Firebase`, I want to know when the `Firebase` has finished loading all child nodes of the data `snapshot` so I can pass back a signal via `handler` that all the data has finished loading.

```
func loadLatestChatConversationMessages(forUserId forId: String!, handler: @escaping (Message?) -> ()){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

    let ref = REF_USERS_MESSAGES.child(uid).child(forId)

    let firstBatchCount: Int = 12

       RefUserMessagesChatConvoHandle = ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: UInt(firstBatchCount)).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

                    let key = child.key


                    self.REF_MESSAGES.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


                        guard var dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }

                        dictionary["messageId"] = key

                        let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)

                        handler(message)

                    }, withCancel: nil)


                }//end for


            } else {
                print("returning - no messages.")
                handler(nil)

            }// end if snapshot.childrenCount

        }, withCancel: nil)


}//end func
```

Comment: Use a dispatchGroup()

Comment: appreciate the feedback, but can you please elaborate or provide a sample perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the top create a dispatchGroup object and enter() right away. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

```
let dg = DispatchGroup()
```

and then in each child download you want to do you enter() and leave() once its done.

then finally you call

```
dg.notify(queue: .main, work: {
    // escape the close
})
```